# How to use Firebase Authentication service and have user in our own database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have my own `node.js` server setup so I don't need Firebase storage and real-time database service. From the client side (mainly Android) I am trying to authenticate the user using  Firebase Authentication service(G+ and FB login) but that creates users in firebase database. How can I create users in my database also?

Currently, I am simply sending user id created by Firebase to my server and saving it in DB and generating a `JWT` to validate subsequent REST API requests to my server.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your client app will get back a [Firebase JWT token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) after end users login with Google/Facebook. Whenever your app needs to send REST API requests to your server, just append the Firebase JWT token into the request body.

On your server, you first validate the Firebase token inside the incoming request. Once the JWT security check passes (signature, audience, expiration etc.), you can extract the 'sub' field (which is the user_id) in the token, and create a user record in your DB only if the user_id is not in DB yet.

Comment: How can we verify the firebase token on backend? Does firebase gives us the secret it uses so we can verify using the same secret?

Comment: You can use Firebase Admin SDK or any third party JWT library to verify Firebase tokens: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk

Comment: Is this efficient?

Comment: Yes. Firebase token can be locally verified in your server. The only RPC involved is to download the public cert from Firebase, which is valid (and can be cached) for several hours.

Comment: I have just started working on this. in the Firebase's `idToken` for users signing up with Google/ Facebook, is there a field in the decoded token that specifies that the user signed up using Google/ Facebook, e.g. would the `firebase.sign_in_provider` be Google/ Facebook?